# awk code to filter lines in one file according to matching conditions in another file

Tags: r, awk

I have two files that look like this:

file1 with 511 lines:

```
chr start end
1 1227897 2779043
1 6644723 8832944
1 11067792 11372913
1 17287414 17342924
1 23254576 23590651
```

file2 with 12594903 lines:

```
CHR POS REF A1 OBS_CT BETA SE P ALT_FREQS RSID_UKB
1 58396 T C 382851 0.0882097 0.0677502 0.192923 0.000249012 rs570371753
1 91588 G A 382852 0.265908 0.0879796 0.00250811 0.000148375 rs554639997
1 713979 C G 382837 0.00630607 0.0925289 0.945664 0.000138059 rs117217250
1 715265 C T 377557 0.00260829 0.00617561 0.672768 0.0331599 rs12184267
1 715367 A G 377954 0.00212642 0.00615857 0.729886 0.0333038 rs12184277
1 717485 C A 377980 0.00449142 0.00615965 0.465899 0.0332908 rs12184279
1 6702159 G T 378749 0.00305772 0.00604916 0.613223 0.0345562 rs116801199
1 9902231 G C 378573 0.00216983 0.00607117 0.720793 0.0342995 rs12565286
1 23364524 C G 377155 0.00505093 0.00588132 0.390447 0.0368034 rs2977670
```

I am trying to remove all lines in file2 where `POS` (i.e. position) in file2 is in between `start` and `end` of file1 and and where `CHR` in file2 is equal to `chr` in file1. I can do it with R and the following code but it takes approx. 1 hour to run it this way:

```
for (row in 1:nrow(file1)) {
  file2 <- file2[!(file2$CHR == file1$chr[row] &
                      file2$POS >= file1$start[row] &
                      file2$POS <= file1$end[row])]
}
```

The output is meant to look like this, with the 2 lines (line 7 and 9) that meet the conditions removed:

```
CHR POS REF A1 OBS_CT BETA SE P ALT_FREQS RSID_UKB
1 58396 T C 382851 0.0882097 0.0677502 0.192923 0.000249012 rs570371753
1 91588 G A 382852 0.265908 0.0879796 0.00250811 0.000148375 rs554639997
1 713979 C G 382837 0.00630607 0.0925289 0.945664 0.000138059 rs117217250
1 715265 C T 377557 0.00260829 0.00617561 0.672768 0.0331599 rs12184267
1 715367 A G 377954 0.00212642 0.00615857 0.729886 0.0333038 rs12184277
1 717485 C A 377980 0.00449142 0.00615965 0.465899 0.0332908 rs12184279
1 9902231 G C 378573 0.00216983 0.00607117 0.720793 0.0342995 rs12565286
```

There must be a neat and quick awk one-liner to do this. I can't figure out how, though. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What's the expected output for the given sample data?

Comment: So the output should look exactly like file2, but those lines that match the conditions should be removed.

Comment: Sure, please add the expected output to the question. I'd like to have something to compare my results to. Thanks!

Comment: Ah, sure. Have added the expected output!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a very quick and ugly way to do it. At just creates a list indexed by all possibilities:

```
awk '(NR==FNR) {for(i=$2;i<=$3;++i) a[$1,i]; next}(FNR==1);!(($1,$2) in a)' file1 file2
```

The problem is that, even though it is quickly written down, it is very slow ;-)

A quicker way might be:

```
awk '(NR==FNR) { a[$1]=a[$1] FS $2 FS $3; next}
     { t=$0;c=$1;p=$2; $0=a[c] }
     { for(i=1;i<=NF;i+=2) if( $i<=p && p<=$(i+1) ) next; print t }' file1 file2
```

In the latter, we create lists like:

```
a[1] = "1227897 2779043 6644723 8832944 11067792 11372913"
```

Every time a new record of file2 is read, we store the record under `t` and keep track of the `CHR` value (`c=$1`). By assigning `a[c]` to `$0` we recompute all the fields, so `$1=1227897`, `$2=2779043`, etc. So all we have to do is jump in groups of two over all the fields and check if the current record lays in the respective range or not. If it lays in the range, we skip to the next record.

As is mentioned in the [comment of SiegeX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61769626/awk-code-to-filter-lines-in-one-file-according-to-matching-conditions-in-another/61771379?noredirect=1#comment109281717_61771379), this can be sped up if `file2` is sorted:

```
 awk '(NR==FNR) { a[$1]=a[$1] FS $2 FS $3 FS a[$1]; next}
     { t=$0;c=$1;p=$2; $0=a[c] }
     { for(i=NF-1;i>0;i+=2) {
          if ( $(i+1) < p ) { $i=$(i+1)=""; $0=$0; $1=$1; a[c]=$0 }
          else if ( $i<=p && p<=$(i+1) ) { next }
          print t
     }' file1 file2
```

Comment: Your output is opposite of what he is looking for.  You're printing the lines that match the condition when they should be removed

Comment: Much quicker, thanks a lot! Now I just need to up my awk game until I understand what is happening here.

Comment: @kvantour clever to make records that key off of the `CHR` variable.  One way you can get a logarithmic speed up is to cull your hash map of ranges as soon as one of the records' `POS` goes beyond one pair of ranges.  For example, as soon as the record with `POS` equal to `6702159` is reached, you can remove the range pair `1227897 2779043` from `a[1]` so you no longer have to compare further records against it.  This only works if file2 is sorted by `POS`, but it appears to be that way from the sample file we are given.

Comment: @SiegeX thanks. I've added an update to it. Because of how fields redefine $0, I had to do some hocus-pocus to get the desired result, but I think this should do it.

Comment: @kvantour @SiegeX Yes, file2 is indeed sorted by ```CHR``` and by ```POS```

Answer (score 1):

```
awk '
  NR==FNR{
    a[$2","$3]=$1
    next
  } 

  {
    for(i in a){
      split(i,b,",")
      if($1 == a[i] && $2 >= b[1] && $2 <= b[2]){next}
    }
  }1
' file1 file2
```

#### Proof of Concept

***Note***: I added an extra line of input in file2 with a `CHR` different than `1` to test that condition

```
$ cat file2
CHR POS REF A1 OBS_CT BETA SE P ALT_FREQS RSID_UKB
1 58396 T C 382851 0.0882097 0.0677502 0.192923 0.000249012 rs570371753
1 91588 G A 382852 0.265908 0.0879796 0.00250811 0.000148375 rs554639997
1 713979 C G 382837 0.00630607 0.0925289 0.945664 0.000138059 rs117217250
1 715265 C T 377557 0.00260829 0.00617561 0.672768 0.0331599 rs12184267
1 715367 A G 377954 0.00212642 0.00615857 0.729886 0.0333038 rs12184277
1 717485 C A 377980 0.00449142 0.00615965 0.465899 0.0332908 rs12184279
1 6702159 G T 378749 0.00305772 0.00604916 0.613223 0.0345562 rs116801199
1 9902231 G C 378573 0.00216983 0.00607117 0.720793 0.0342995 rs12565286
1 23364524 C G 377155 0.00505093 0.00588132 0.390447 0.0368034 rs2977670
2 23364524 C G 377155 0.00505093 0.00588132 0.390447 0.0368034 rs2977670

$ awk 'NR==FNR{a[$2","$3]=$1;next}{for(i in a){split(i,b,",");\
         if($1 == a[i] && $2 >= b[1] && $2 <= b[2]){next}}}1' file1 file2
CHR POS REF A1 OBS_CT BETA SE P ALT_FREQS RSID_UKB
1 58396 T C 382851 0.0882097 0.0677502 0.192923 0.000249012 rs570371753
1 91588 G A 382852 0.265908 0.0879796 0.00250811 0.000148375 rs554639997
1 713979 C G 382837 0.00630607 0.0925289 0.945664 0.000138059 rs117217250
1 715265 C T 377557 0.00260829 0.00617561 0.672768 0.0331599 rs12184267
1 715367 A G 377954 0.00212642 0.00615857 0.729886 0.0333038 rs12184277
1 717485 C A 377980 0.00449142 0.00615965 0.465899 0.0332908 rs12184279
1 9902231 G C 378573 0.00216983 0.00607117 0.720793 0.0342995 rs12565286
2 23364524 C G 377155 0.00505093 0.00588132 0.390447 0.0368034 rs2977670
```

Comment: Thanks, seems to be working correctly but is not faster than my R code.